# How can I check for user activity/idle from a Windows service written in Python?

Tags: python, windows, service, user-input, user-inactivity

I've written a Windows service in Python that needs to be able to detect user activity. Under normal circumstances I would call the Windows `GetLastInputInfo` method, but that method doesn't work when called by a service. Here's the relevant info from the documentation for this method:

> This function is useful for input idle detection. However, GetLastInputInfo does not provide system-wide user input information across all running sessions. Rather, GetLastInputInfo provides session-specific user input information for only the session that invoked the function.

The salient point is this: "**for only the session that invoked the function**"

If called by the service, `GetLastInputInfo` will *always* return 0 because the service is running in session 0 and doesn't receive input! How can my service detect user activity from the console session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Caveats Up Front:***

This solution is *tested and working* under Windows 10.

I was able to do some limited testing of this solution under Windows 11, and it seems like mouse activity (button presses and motion) is **not registered**, but key press and key release events *are*. If all you need is key activity detection, this will work. But if you need to monitor mouse events, you're out of luck pending a different/updated solution.

If anyone has an alternative solution for Windows 11, I'm all ears!

---

Fortunately, there's a workaround for this problem! While you can't poll for user activity directly from a service, you *can* check to see if the system is currently handling user input by querying the I/O info for the Windows [Client Server Runtime](https://www.howtogeek.com/321581/what-is-client-server-runtime-process-csrss.exe-and-why-is-it-running-on-my-pc/) process (a.k.a. "csrss.exe").

By leveraging Python's `psutil` module, you can check either the `read_count` or `read_bytes` properties of csrss.exe. These values should change any time there is input from the user, i.e. keystrokes or mouse events.

First, you need to get the process ID (PID) for the csrss.exe process:

```
import psutil


def get_csrss_pids() -> list[int]:
    """Get the PID(s) for the Windows Client Server Runtime process"""
    # NOTE: There will likely be two csrss processes running; one in
    # the Services session (0), and the other in the Console session (1)
    return [
        proc.pid for proc in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['name'])
        if proc.name() == 'csrss.exe'
    ]
```

Once you have your csrss.exe PID(s), you can use `psutil`'s `io_counters` method to get the `read_count` or `read_bytes` info (both will update any time there's user input - I use `read_bytes` below)

```
def get_io(pids: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    """Returns the last `read_bytes` value for the given csrss.exe PID(s)"""
    # NOTE: if multiple PIDs are given, it's likely that only one of the PIDs
    # 'read_bytes' values will be changing on user input because one of these
    # processes is for your current session and the others aren't
    return [psutil.Process(pid).io_counters().read_bytes for pid in pids]
```

The `get_io` function will return a list of integers corresponding to the `read_bytes` values for each of the given csrss.exe process IDs. To check for user activity, this list should be periodically compared to a previously stored value - any changes mean there's been input from the user!

Here's a quick demo:

```
import psutil


def get_csrss_pids() -> list[int]:
    """Get the PID(s) for the Windows Client Server Runtime process"""
    return [
        proc.pid for proc in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['name'])
        if proc.name() == 'csrss.exe'
    ]


def get_io(pids: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    """Returns the last `read_bytes` value for the given csrss.exe PID(s)"""
    return [psutil.Process(pid).io_counters().read_bytes for pid in pids]


pids = get_csrss_pids()
last_io = get_io(pids)  # store an initial value to compare against

while True:
    try:
        if (tick := get_io(pids)) != last_io:  # if activity is detected...
            print(tick)  # do something
            last_io = tick  # store the new value to compare against
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```

To incorporate these functions into your service, simply include them in your main class (the one subclassing `ServiceFramework`) - don't forget to add the `self` parameter!

You'll want to call `get_csrss_pids` and set the initial value of `last_io` at `__init__` and go from there:

```
class MyService(ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = 'my_service'
    _svc_display_name_ = 'My Service'

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.csrss_pids = self.get_csrss_pids()
        self.last_io = self.get_io()
        ...
```

Comment: not working for a mouse in windows 11.

Comment: Hmm...I'm afraid I've only used this technique on Windows 10. I haven't had the chance to try it on Windows 11 - there may be some differences there.

Comment: This has a [XKCD:Workflow](https://xkcd.com/1172/) smell. Abusing a counter value that's in no way documented as an official API. These things could have broken in any W10 patch.

Comment: @MSalters It's definitely a hack, no bones about it. If you have an alternative solution, I'm definitely open to it...as ever, XKCD is right.