# How can I watch for user activity from a service (session 0) in Windows 11?

Tags: python, service, windows-11, user-activity

I came up with the solution below to watch for user activity from a service. This is working as expected in Windows 10, but doesn't work for mouse activity in Windows 11 (only key press/release events are detected); evidently something has changed *WRT* the behavior of csrss.exe under Windows 11.

I've looked into all of the available information returned by `psutil` for csrss.exe and wasn't able to come up with an alternative approach to monitoring mouse activity in Windows 11. Ultimately, my question is: How can I watch for user activity from a service (session 0) in Windows 11?

I'm trying to find an approach that I can use either in conjunction with or instead of my existing solution - any help/info is much appreciated!

*More info on this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76130069/how-can-i-check-for-user-activity-idle-from-a-windows-service-written-in-python) in a Q/A detailing my initial solution.*

```
import psutil


def get_csrss_pids() -> list[int]:
    """Get the PID(s) for the Windows Client Server Runtime process"""
    return [
        proc.pid for proc in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['name'])
        if proc.name() == 'csrss.exe'
    ]


def get_io(pids: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    """Returns the last `read_bytes` value for the given csrss.exe PID(s)"""
    return [psutil.Process(pid).io_counters().read_bytes for pid in pids]


pids = get_csrss_pids()
last_io = get_io(pids)  # store an initial value to compare against

while True:
    try:
        if (tick := get_io(pids)) != last_io:  # if activity is detected...
            print(tick)  # do something
            last_io = tick  # store the new value to compare against
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows, keyboard and mouse input is associated with the *interactive window station*. This window station has a well-known name, `"WinSta0"`.

As you've figured out, `WinSta0` is the window station of an interactive session, which is definitely not session 0. Services are not interactive. This means you cannot call `OpenWindowStationA("WinSta0")` from a service.

This is intentional. Since Windows XP, Microsoft has been continuously increasing security. User Interface Isolation has been in Windows since Windows Vista. It seems that Windows 11 has taken yet another step, and that's not exactly surprising. `csrss.exe` is an implementation detail of Windows; it's currently a per-session process. (That's why you could find multiple). Only the `csrss.exe` of the `WinSta0`  session would deal with keyboard and mouse, previously.

Logically, that means that the other `csrss` processes had unnecessary code. It only makes sense to refactor `csrss` into interactive and non-interactive parts, so the Windows 11 change is not that weird.

Given that Windows changes and continues to change, the logical answer is to take one step back. If you need the *interactive window station* in one way or another, then you need to run code in that session. That means it does not run as a service. Your service can start another process in another session, and communicate with that second process, but it has to be isolated.

Comment: So my best bet is to have my application handle the activity monitoring and use some form of IPC to communicate with the backend service? For the sake of transparency, I've implemented a service to handle things that require elevated permissions, and to launch my application after a given timeout in minutes of inactivity, and I need that timeout to reset on user activity (not unlike a screensaver). FWIW, the service doesn't need to communicate *back* to the main app - it just needs to be able to keep an eye on activity.

Comment: Or, if I'm understanding correctly, do I need both the "backend" (handling admin-level stuff) and the "frontend" running in the same session?

Comment: You already have an interactive application? Put the UI stuff there. Checking for user input _is_ UI. I don't understand what part of your application requires that service; it seems to solve no problems but does create additional problems. Part of your problem might be Python; it's not a language with a native OS binding. Starting a python app hidden, and only creating a _window_ on timeout is going to be harder than it would be in C++

Comment: The issue I have (which prompted the creation of the service in the first place) is that I (or more accurately, the end user) can't run the main app with admin rights. But there are things I need the app to do that require them. To that end, the service handles the elevated stuff so the user isn't involved. The interactive part of the app is, as said, only part of the whole equation.

Comment: The other point is that the UI necessarily *won't* be running until the inactivity timeout, so I can't monitor activity there unless I, as you said, start it hidden and only open the main window after the timeout (which isn't a non-starter, certainly - I'd just need to do some re-tooling)

Comment: You could just write a very simple C or C++ wrapper and use Python embedding (but only load the whole Python thing when needed)